# INSERT INTO MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert

I have a MySQL table ( members ) with six columns ( FirstName, LastName, Email, username, password, Key)

I need to insert a string into the **Key** column for the **username** ***admin***

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is your DB schema set up to accept strings in the key column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the string you want to insert is the literal string `'MyString'`. You could update the table like this:

```
UPDATE `members` SET `Key` = 'MyString' WHERE `username` = 'admin'
```

Some things to note:

- I've enclosed the column names, such as `Key`, in *identifier quotes* (backticks). This is mainly because I know that MySQL may treat the word 'key' as an SQL reserved word, which might result in it failing to parse my UPDATE query.
- This assumes that the column `Key` has a string datatype, such as `TEXT` or `CHAR(20)`. If it doesn't (for example if it's an `INT`), then it doesn't make sense to try to update it to contain a string.
- I also assume that the column length, if it's a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, is long enough to contain this string (i.e. it's of length at least 8). If the column is too short to contain the string I'm trying to put in it, then MySQL will either truncate the string or issue an error message, depending on the SQL mode.

Alternatively, if there isn't a row in the table for which `username` is 'admin', but you want to insert one, you use

```
INSERT INTO `members` (`username`, `key`) VALUES ('admin', 'MyString')
```

This statement is subject to the same provisos as the one above. Also, any columns that are `NOT NULL` will need to have values specified as well (with the possible exception of an auto-incrementing integer field).

Comment: I used this code, but it doesn't do anything. It doesn't even display an error.

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE members`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I finally figured it out. Thank you for your help! I'm posting another now. I have some PHP code that doesn't seem to work. Want to give it a try and help out? :-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE members 
   SET `Key`='<SOMETHING>' 
 WHERE username='admin' 
 LIMIT 1
```

You should have a primary key, like `member_id` (usually an `INT` with `auto_increment`). Then you can do:

```
UPDATE members 
   SET `Key`='<SOMETHING>' 
 WHERE member_id=<X>
```

Comment: +50000 for always having a numeric auto_incrment primary key. If you need to have another column function in a similar manner to a primary key use a unique index. also you might want to stay away from using the column name `key` as it is used by mysql as a keyword. use `member_key` or something like that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know whether or not that user exists use ON DUPLICATE...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html